# How to mock an offline Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Controller with an endpoint. I would like to disable this endpoint at runtime so that it looks like the application is offline for the user.

Currently doing this to disable the endpoint:

```
private static final Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> requestMappings = new HashMap<>();

this.context.getHandlerMethods().forEach((k, v) -> {
    if (k.getPatternsCondition().getPatterns().contains("/customer")) {
      requestMappings.put(k, v);
    }
});
requestMappings.forEach((k, v) -> this.context.unregisterMapping(k));
```

And this to enable:

```
requestMappings.forEach((k, v) -> this.context.registerMapping(k, v.getBean(), v.getMethod()));
requestMappings.clear();
```

This works like a charm, the beans are unregistered and registered at runtime. However when the user calls my application they get a 404 instead of a Connection timed out, which is what I was looking for.

I do understand why I am getting a 404. Requests still enter the application but the path isn't found because the beans aren't registered so it return s a 404. How do I go about tackling an  "actual offline" situation that doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Your definition of "offline" seems a bit confusing. 'Offline' to me means 'not running'. If you want a connection time-out then that to me implies that the port needs to be open, the connection accepted but then dropped by the client after waiting for too long. That is not the same as 'offline'. If it were offline, it wouldn't get a connection on the port in the first place. And to accomplish this you just removed resources. Why would that cause any reasonable web server implementation to timeout? It can see the lack of the resource immediately, so it returns with that error... immediately.

Comment: Well for the client to run into a timeout, you'd need to actually offer the endpoint but never return anything, no?

Comment: @Michael Indeed, that's what I'm trying to say in my last bit of text.

Comment: @daniu You're right. I understood this after creating the above code hence why I came here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what can be a use-case for such a scenario.

There are some approaches I can think of though:

1. Just stop the application. As was already stated in comments - the client will try to connect and will eventually run into connection timeout.
2. Restart the application context "programmatically" without restarting the whole JVM. There is a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app) about doing this.

The second approach can be appealing only in conjunction with a property `spring.main.web-environment=false` that you should supply during the application context restart.

Comment: We use a Docker container that represents a service that a 3rd party offers for use in automated tests. One of our test cases is that the application is offline. Your second option looks very interesting.. only we interact with the Docker container over rest to disable it. So turning the api back on would be impossible.

Comment: Yeah, turning back through the rest won't be possible. The trigger doesn't have to be a rest API though (a file, a record in the database, a message through messaging system, whatever)... On the other hand if you already have docker, why don't you just stop the container and then bring it back? BTW, do you have kubernetes as well? because if you do, then you can just interact with kubernetes api and set number of replicas to 0 and then to 1 when you want the app back...

Comment: I like your ideas. Bringing the container up and down might actually be the easiest. I was curious about other opinions/possibilities. Thanks for the help, I know what to do :-)